# How to create SecurityGroupIngress objects?

Tags: java, aws-cdk

`.securityGroupIngress()` of `CfnSecurityGroup.Builder` takes a `List<Object> securityGroupIngress`. I'm trying to add an ingress rule to a security group:

```
CfnSecurityGroupIngress ingressRule =
    CfnSecurityGroupIngress.Builder.create(this, "IngressRule")
            .ipProtocol("tcp")
            .fromPort(80)
            .toPort(80)
            .cidrIp("0.0.0.0/0")
            .build();

List<Object> ingressRules = new ArrayList<>();
ingressRules.add(ingressRule)
```

And then:

```
CfnSecurityGroup.Builder.create(this, "SecurityGroup")
        .groupName("ALB-SG")
        .groupDescription("Allow traffic from the Internet to the ALB")
        .vpcId(vpc.getRef())
        .securityGroupIngress(ingressRules) // <-- 
        .build();
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

`Caused by: software.amazon.jsii.JsiiException: Resolution error: Resolution error: Trying to resolve() a Construct at /Resources/${Token[SGStack.SecurityGroup.LogicalID.39]}/Properties/securityGroupIngress/0/node.`

A point of confusion for me is the `List<Object>` required by `.securityGroupIngress()` because in CloudFormation, the `SecurityGroupIngress` `(CfnSecurityGroupIngress)` property of an `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` `(CfnSecurityGroup)` takes a list of `Ingress` objects. Why is it `List<Object>` and not `List<CfnSecurityGroupIngressProps>` or `List<CfnSecurityGroupIngress>`? But most importantly, how do I create this `List<Object>` that is required?

Answer (score 2):

Use `software.amazon.awscdk.services.ec2.CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty` instead of `CfnSecurityGroupIngress`:

```
IngressProperty
    .builder()
    .fromPort(80)
    .toPort(80)
    .ipProtocol("tcp")
    .cidrIp("0.0.0.0/0")
    .build()
```